# lapply columns of dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

I'm having difficulty creating standardised column types. I'm writing a function that goes from column to column, looks up what data type it should be from another list and then changes the column format to that type.

```
as.data.frame(lapply(claims, 
 function(fun.col){

   col.type <- claims.mapping$type[match(colnames(fun.col),
                                         claims.mapping$col.name.std)]

   if (is.na(col.type)) {
     #Do nothing
   } else if (col.type == "Date") {
     as.Date(fun.col[], origin = "1900-01-01")
   } 
 }))
```

This gives the error

> Error in if (is.na(col.type)) { : argument is of length zero

I think the issue arises from not being sure how lapply passes its argument to the function. How would I fix this?

Example data:

```
claims <- structure(list(a = c(13245, 43220, 45221), b = 1:3), row.names = (NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

claims.mapping <- structure(list(col.name.std = structure(1:3, .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), x = c("Date", "numeric", "character")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Expected output:

```
structure(list(a = structure(c(-12322, 17653, 19654), class = "Date"), b = 1:3), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Your sample data throws an error (there is a typo in `claims`); there are more entries in `claims.mapping` than there are columns in `claims`. Is that always the case?

Comment: Yeah. There are a lot of different data sources that get compared to the same central map. As such, the claims.mapping is about triple the length of each colnames vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it using `mapply`. You need to change your strategies a bit. Pass `names` of `claims` to function in `mapply` and then return converted data from `claims` data.frame.

```
as.data.frame(mapply(function(fun.col){
  col.type <- claims.mapping$x[match(fun.col,
                                        claims.mapping$col.name.std)]

  if (is.na(col.type)) {
    claims[,fun.col]
  } else if (col.type == "Date") {
    as.Date(claims[,fun.col], origin = "1990-01-01")
  } else{
    claims[,fun.col]
  }
},names(claims), SIMPLIFY = FALSE))

#            a b
# 1 2026-04-07 1
# 2 2108-05-02 2
# 3 2113-10-24 3
```

**Corrected data from OP:**

```
claims <- structure(list(a = c(13245, 43220, 45221), b = 1:3), .Names = c("a", "b"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
          structure(list(a = 10:20, b = 21:31), .Names = c("a", "b"), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame")

claims.mapping <- structure(list(col.name.std = structure(1:3, .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), x = c("Date", "numeric", "character")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Pretty much worked entirely correctly. Only change that had to be made was changing `claims[, fun.col]` to `claims[[fun.col]]` as one's treated as a list and the other as the data itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can include the functions in the order needed. ie then call them from there as shown

```
claims.mapping$fun=c(function(x)as.Date(x,"1990-01-01"),as.numeric,as.character)
ss=function(x,y) with(claims.mapping,fun[col.name.std==y][[1]])(x)
data.frame(Map(ss ,claims,names(claims)))
           a b
1 1936-04-07 1
2 2018-05-02 2
3 2023-10-24 3
```

or you can try

```
data.frame(Map( function(i,j)
{
 k= c(function(x)as.Date(x,"1900-01-01"),as.numeric,as.character)
 k[claims.mapping$col.name.std==j][[1]](i) 
},
claims,names(claims))
)
           a b
1 1936-04-07 1
2 2018-05-02 2
3 2023-10-24 3
```